# Is it possible to stack ARIMA and PROPHET models for predictions?

Tags: python, statistics, arima, facebook-prophet, ensemble-learning

Suppose I have **Arima** and **Prophet** model and i want to use stacking on them for future predictions.

For example, I have a dataframe with *Volume*, *Price* and *Date* column. I want to predict *Price* for future days which are not in dataframe (example: last date in dataframe is *16.03.2022* and i want to make predictions on *17.03.2022, 18.03.2022* . So there is no data except for the date for them)

There are some examples which show how to predict in the future using these models separately, but there is no example how **Arima** and **Prophet** can be stacked and then used to predict in the future.

Comment: Most naive way would be to use both predictions and take an average.